# How can I change the apple ID that xcode uses to update?

Tags: xcode

A colleague of mine installed xCode on my Mac using his AppleId, and now AppStore asks for his ID in order to update it.

I read the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997317/how-can-i-change-the-apple-id-that-xcode-4-uses-to-download-components post, but it doesn't work for me since I cannot find his account in KeyChain. Do you have another idea?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try deleting it (in Finder remove /Applications/Xcode) and reinstalling it? Your projects and settings won't be affected.

Comment: I would just uninstall and reinstall the application.